# SoundCloud testing - test samples?

Tags: testing, soundcloud

Are their available on SoundCloud test tracks I can download without upsetting any download limits?

Answer (score 2):

In general, tracks uploaded by users with Solo, Pro, or Pro Plus accounts don't have download limits (if the uploader has enabled downloads for that track, of course). [1](http://soundcloud.com/premium)